# Screen resolution trouble in different browsers with Aurelia Framework

Tags: html, css, frameworks, aurelia

I'm learning more about Aurelia and while trying to migrate some layouts from HTML5 to Aurelia, I found that everything looks bigger when inside an aurelia template. Even the simplest layout possible, without any css styling or lib, looks bigger here compared with the raw HTML.

My monitor resolution is 1920 x 1080 and looking in Developer Tools, the HTML tag width is smaller (1920px width in HTML file vs 1280px in Aurelia rendered page).

I also tried my app in Google Chrome, Mozilla Firefox and Microsoft Edge and the only showing it how it should on both examples is Edge.

Here is a screenshot of same application on both browsers:
[image: Screenshot]

Playing with zoom on developer mode I discovered that if you put zoom: 1.5 on the left one, it gets the same size of the right one and zoom: 0.66 on right get the same of the left.

Does anyone know how to fix this? I'm getting crazy about it!!

Edit:
Here is another example with Chrome and Firefox. Attention to the sizes:
[image]

No css at all on these examples!

Comment: This is more of a bootstrap question than an Aurelia question. You might want to tag it as such.

Comment: Even with only HTML (without any CSS), the problem occurs. That's why I think that's Aurelia doing something I'm missing.

Comment: Here's what I see in Chrome for the exact same HTML, save one rendered by Aurelia, the other not: http://i.imgur.com/XhCdBv9.png They're exactly the same, down to the pixel.

Comment: Currently I'm using my laptop with an external screen. The laptop one has a 4k resolution and the external is a full-hd but both are configured as 1920x1080px. Do you think that's could be the problem?

Comment: It might very well be. Without physically being at your computer though, it's hard to say.

Answer (score 0):

Since I didn't find why it was happening, I reinstalled my browsers and the problem is gone! I failed figuring out the reason it was happening but for now, that's enough for me.